# TYPO3 Add Copy and Paste icons to Content Elements

Tags: typo3, contextmenu, typoscript, typo3-8.x, tsconfig

Is it possible to add icons to the left or right side for Content Elements? I would like to move some of the functionality from the contextMenu to the icon bar, is that possible? Perhaps by TSConfig ? See attachment.

[image: Content elements]

Answer (score 1):

Several options exist for multiple TYPO3 versions and depending on where you would prefer to add the copy/cut icon, or indeed, any other icon you might wish:

- Before 10.3 and without fluid-based page layout module:

  - `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['GLOBAL']['recStatInfoHooks']`
  - `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawFooter']`
  - `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']` through `$outHeader` variable.
- After 10.3 with fluid-based page layout module:

  - All of the above, plus
  - Overlay of template `EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Partials/PageLayout/Record/Header.html`, or
  - Overlay of template `EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Partials/PageLayout/Record/Footer.html`, or
  - Overlay of template `EXT:backend/Resources/Private/Partials/PageLayout/Record.html` depending on where you want the icon to be placed

These should provide you with every conceivable option for adding the icon precisely where you wish it to be added. TYPO3 10.3 with fluid based page module enabled provides you with the createst flexibility. Earlier versions or with fluid based page module disabled should probably use `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['GLOBAL']['recStatInfoHooks']`.

Comment: Thank you @Claus. I must investigate that right away.

Answer (score 0):

I personaly wouldn't add too many button visible by default on the top right of each content, because it will unnecessarily overloads the amount of information on the page module with action buttons that are not the most often used.

In particular, the "paste" button should only appears when there is something in the clipboard, and it now appears everywhere you can paste (you can see one above the content in your screenshot).

Cheers,
Rachel

Comment: @Rachel, but is it possible to add more buttons? As it is today, it is not very user-friendly. A user has no idea that the Context menu exists. And how should the user be able to copy an item? And how should the user be able to copy an item if they do not know that the first icon can be clicked.

Comment: IIRC templavoila had that functionality - I don't think that it is possible to add the icons with just TSConfig

Comment: @Stig you're right when you point the real problem: "A user has no idea that the Context menu exists." I would'nt solve it putting missing buttons visible by default. A workaround for you would be to change the contextual menu button icon in pure CSS so that it's obvious that there is more actions clicking on it. I think that it's easy to override backend CSS ($GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories'][] = 'EXT:my_extension/styles/';) In any case, I'm going to talk to the Structured Content Initiative about it, because we are working on the UX of the page module.

Comment: @Riccardo, The user has previously used TemplaVoilá and now lacks this functionality.

Comment: @Rachel, It might be solved if the Context Menu icon changed to burger menu known from mobile sites. They would indicate a menu.

Thanks to you both!